# CSS position:relative makes page bigger

Tags: html, css

I'm making a page with HTML and CSS and the width of the page is growing as I use

```
position:relative;
left:100px;
```

When I put this code in CSS, the page is pushed to the right 100px making a huge blank area to the right of my website which looks horrible.
Here is a link to my website: [Wagicalmales](http://wagicalmales.co.uk)
If you side scroll right you'll see what I mean.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct behaviour when using `position: relative` (the position is set relative to where it would have been).

I'm assuming the element you are having issues with is the `h1` with the 'WagicalMales' text it. To fix your problem change `left:200px` to `margin-left:200px`.